# How to bring WiX Bundle ExePackage to foreground when running

Tags: wix, bundle

I have a WiX Bundle that I am creating to bootstrap some required prerequisites on a client computer.  I deploy these prerequisite programs via their exe installers.  Everything seems to work fine except the exe installer UIs run behind the Bundle UI.  For some of these installers this is no problem as they require no interaction, but for a couple of them I want the user to interact with that product's installer, set options in it etc..  The user can click on the installer UI in the background to bring it forward, but it is a bit confusing for someone who hasn't done that before.

I am using WiX 3.7 and the bootstrapped exe installers in question are for PostgreSQL and PostGIS.

So my question is how do I get the target of an exe package to run in the foreground...or conversely how to do I get the WiX Bundle UI to go to the background or hide while the ExePackage is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is that Windows does a lot of work to fight executables taking over z-order. This is to prevent those annoying apps that try to launch stuff in your face.

Burn does ensure the Bootstrapper Application hwnd always gets the right z-order (so it doesn't end up blinking in the task bar like many other bootstrappers). On top of that, the Window installer allows external UI handlers (like Burn) to provide a window handle to ensure that any presented MSI UI ends up on top of that window. Unfortunately, `::CreateProcess()` does not provide such a mechanism so see the current behavior.

You can try to write custom BA code to do battle with Windows to find then bring the newly launched executables' windows to the forefront (I think it'll be possible because your BA will have the top z-order and can give it away).

Personally, I might instead try to encompass the configuration in the BA and run the other pacakges silent.

Comment: Thanks Rob that makes it a bit clearer now.  By custom BA code, I assume you mean creating something like a WPF Managed Bootstrapper Application (MBA) as there are no custom actions in a bundle project. I'm not sure if I have time for that right now, so I will probably just live with clicking to bring launched exe procs to the foreground.

Comment: You can write a custom BA in native or managed code. Your choice.